# How to include PHP script into JSF page under tomcat or resin?

Tags: php, jsf, tomcat, resin, caucho

I have worked JSF application under Tomcat. In the same project I configured, also using, PHP as described in Caucho Resin site ([Link](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.1/doc/quercus.xtp))

But when I try to include separated PHP working script into JSG page, page is fails.

I have `test.php` with:

```
<?php
print "hello world";
?>
```

in `web.xml` I have added:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Quercus Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.caucho.quercus.servlet.QuercusServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>license-directory</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/licenses</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet> 

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Quercus Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.php</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Also added `resin.jar` into `web-inf/lib`

when I call `test.php` directly it is working, but when I try to include like this:

```
<ui:include src="test.php"/>
```

or write php code direct in JSF page it fails.

Here is the exception:

```
javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /test.php: Error Traced[line: 5] Premature end of file.
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:429)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:403)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:124)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:319)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.access$100(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:92)
```

Any body tried this kind of experiment?

Answer (score 1):

When you're calling your PHP page directly, it is being processed by your Quercus Servlet with no problem at all. But when you call your PHP page included inside a non-PHP page, like a JSP (or JSF or XHTML or another file extension), your Quercus Servlet is not processing it thus giving you this errors.

You could do a mix of parsing the page with both Quercus Servlet and/or Faces Servlet (I haven't tested this so I'm not sure if it will work). Another option could be not using the PHP scripts in your JSP/JSF pages directly but using them to process the actions i.e. `<form action="test.php">`.

Note that this is not a JSF nor Tomcat nor Resin nor Caucho problem, it is a servlet problem or an ever worse, a design problem. This leads to a question: Why would you want such an odd design in your web application?

Comment: Directly not needed use php in JSF application, but I try to do this because if your application became large may be you will need some php scripts for specific problems, but actually it is just test.

Comment: I don't really get your point here: *if your application became large maybe you will need some php scripts for specific problems*. When you have one of these *specific problems* come here and post it , I'm sure there is a solution using Java